# Stripe - STPPaymentCardTextField - Remove border

Tags: ios, stripe-payments

Stripe's iOS SDK's "STPPaymentCardTextField" has a borderColor property.

I'm trying to remove it using a new color or setting to nil without success.

Is there a way for programmatically remove the border of the STPPaymentCardTextField?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, adding to the User defined runtime attributes in the Storyboard:

```
layer.borderColor > Color > white
borderColor > Color > white
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an outlet

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet STPPaymentCardTextField *paymentTextField;
```

and then in viewDidLoad

```
self.paymentTextField.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
```